# When does Bitcoin Core allow you to "Abandon transaction"?

Tags: bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions

Right-clicking on an unconfirmed transaction pops up a contextual menu that has the option "Abandon transaction". It is usually grayed out. How much time needs to pass for Bitcoin Core to allow one to choose "Abandon transaction"?

When I run `abandontransaction` on my transaction, it says:

> Transaction not eligible for abandonment (code -5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the source:

[`src/wallet/wallet.cpp`:1290](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/ac9fa6ec78158e41006d621ee62e44dec0f934c0/src/wallet/wallet.cpp#L1290):

```cpp
return wtx && !wtx->isAbandoned() && GetTxDepthInMainChain(*wtx) == 0 && !wtx->InMempool();
```

Basically, it's abandoned if it's dropped out of one's own node's mempool.

Comment: @MichaelFolkson Sure, the TXN could be in _someone's_ mempool. (And technically a miner could mine the pre-RBF transaction…)

Comment: The last sentence would be more precise if it were something like: “it _can be_ abandoned only if it has been dropped from _your own node’s mempool_”.

Answer (score 2):

The option to abandon a transaction is only available if a) it has not been abandoned before, b) neither the transaction or a conflicting transaction is confirmed, and c) the transaction is **not in your own node’s mempool**.

Note that even when you abandon a transaction it might still be retained by other nodes. The only way to be sure that your original transaction cannot be mined in the future is to create a conflicting transaction that spends some of the same inputs and get it confirmed in the blockchain. This is exactly the intent behind `abandontransaction`. You inform your wallet that you are no longer pursuing confirmation for the abandoned transaction which instructs the wallet to permit reuse of the inputs used in it.

Comment: How do I drop the transaction from my own mempool in Bitcoin Core?

Comment: Hi @LOST, if you have a new question, please start a new topic.